# How to configure Cura to run the Z probe before heating

Tags: software, ultimaker-cura, slicing, calibration, z-probe

I'm using Cura as my slicing/printing software and I just started using the BuildTak printing surface.

The BuildTak is damaged by pushing a hot nozzle into it and my printer's (Robo3D R1+) autoleveling feature works by pushing the nozzle into the build surface.

Is there a way to configure Cura so that it runs the Z probe first, then heat up the nozzle?

My first sheet of BuildTak already has 10 small holes in it (at the homing position and at the 9 leveling touch points)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Cura (and Slic3r), you can 100% customize what the printer does before printing your actual model through custom **start/end g-code**.

If you navigate to the `Start/End-GCode tab in Cura`, then select `start.gcode`, you can see what operations are run before each print begins. Lines prefixed with `;` are comments, and does not affect the printing in any way.

Basically, we want to manually tell the printer to do the auto leveling *before* heating up the nozzle by editing the g-code in `start.gcode`.

#### G-Code generated with the default start.gcode:

If you try to slice some model with the default code found in `start.gcode`, you will get something like the following (depending on your printer):

```
; CURA AUTOMATICALLY INSERTS THESE TEMPERATURE CODES

M190 S70.000000 ; Set bed temperature to 70 degrees
M109 S210.000000 ; Set nozzle temperature to 210 degrees


; THESE ARE THE CODES FROM START.GCODE (for a ROBO 3D R1) 

G28          ;move printer to endstops (the home position)
G92 E0       ;zero the extruded filament length
M565 Z-1     ;set z-probe offset
G1 Z5 F5000  ;move the printer 5mm above the bed
G29          ;run auto-leveling


; THE ACTUAL MODEL BEGINS HERE

;Layer count: 168
;LAYER:0
.
.
```

#### Analyzing the g-code output

At the top of this code snippet, we can see that Cura automatically inserts g-code for heating up the bed and nozzle to their respective temperatures with the [M190](http://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M190:_Wait_for_bed_temperature_to_reach_target_temp) and [M109](http://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M109:_Set_Extruder_Temperature_and_Wait) g-codes. This means the printer always will heat up the nozzle before reading the `start.gcode`s that we set. However, if we manually override [M109](http://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M109:_Set_Extruder_Temperature_and_Wait) code in `start.gcode`, the [M109](http://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M109:_Set_Extruder_Temperature_and_Wait) at the top will automagically disappear from the generated g-code output! (Thanks, @TomvanderZanden!)

We could therefore use the auto-leveling command [G29](http://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#G29:_Detailed_Z-Probe) before manually setting the nozzle temperature with [M109](http://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M109:_Set_Extruder_Temperature_and_Wait); specifically, we want to add `M109 S{print_temperature}`, which reads the `Basic -> Print Temperature`-setting in Cura, and replace `{print_temperature}` with it automatically.

#### Manipulating start.gcode:

In order to postpone heating the hotend till after probing, `start.gcode` could be something like:

```
G28          ;move printer to endstops (the home position)
G92 E0       ;zero the extruded filament length
M565 Z-1     ;set z-probe offset     <-----   ( YOU HAVE TO ADJUST THIS, READ BELOW)
G1 Z5 F5000  ;move the printer 5mm above the bed
G29          ;run auto-leveling
M109 S{print_temperature}    ;set nozzle temperature, and wait for it heat up
```

And that's about it! You can then use these codes in your `start.gcode`. However, you probably will have to recalibrate your z-prove offset.

#### Adjust z-probe offset:

Normally, auto-leveling is done with the nozzle heated for a reason: when the nozzle is warm, it expands slightly, moving closer to the bed. You might therefore have to adjust your Z-probe offset with the [M565](http://reprap.org/wiki/G-code#M565:_Set_Z_probe_offset) command (as demonstrated in the snippet) to account for the increase in nozzle length when warm.

#### Remember:

Remember that when editing g-code in this manner, you will take full control of how the printer operates. You could therefore very well do something unintended, so keep the power switch close!

Comment: This answer misses a very important point: in Cura (and something similar works for Slic3r and Simplify3D) you can insert "M109 S{print_temperature}" into your G-code. It will replace {print_temperature} with the set printing temperature and not add its own M109. This way you don't need to do the ugly hack of setting the temp to 0.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden, you are entirely right! I didn't think that Cura would be smart enough to remove the first M109 if you set it manually in start.gcode, but it seems like it is! I will update the answer.

Comment: `{print_temperature}` didn't work for me. `{material_print_temperature}` did. [Look here for more.](https://ultimaker.com/en/community/49978-changing-cura-generated-start-code)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in [Markus's comment](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/454/how-to-configure-cura-to-run-the-z-probe-before-heating/469#comment6403_469) to [Tormod's answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/469/4762), `{print_temperature}` needs to be replaced by `{material_print_temperature}`, so the code now becomes:

```
G28          ;move printer to endstops (the home position)
G92 E0       ;zero the extruded filament length
M565 Z-1     ;set z-probe offset     <-----   ( YOU HAVE TO ADJUST THIS, READ BELOW)
G1 Z5 F5000  ;move the printer 5mm above the bed
G29          ;run auto-leveling
M109 S{material_print_temperature}    ;set nozzle temperature, and wait for it heat up
```